# Map secondary domain to other's virtual subfolder

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a Wordpress site and there's a request to map `otherdomain.com` to `maindomain.com/virtualsubfolder/` (the WP site). This can be easily done, but the URL structure should remain intact i.e. `otherdomain.com/something/` should redirect to `maindomain.com/virtualsubfolder/something/` but the URL in the client side should remain `otherdomain.com/something/`

I know it's a pretty common problem, but i still couldn't find any viable solution.

I'm open to any ideas using Apache's mod_rewrite or even Nginx.

Thanks for your help.